.Net 8 - Http Client - GET Call - Kerberos Authentication - Invalid Token Issue
We have an existing application in .Net 6 hosted in our firm which consumes a REST API exposed by another system within our firm. The application works just fine and gets the data from the REST API. Our firm has SSO and kerberos auth set up.
We upgraded the solution to .Net 8 and we started facing the Authentication validation failed with error - InvalidToken. We did not modify any code and could not find much help regarding this.
We expected the system to behave the same way post upgrade.
